Gremlin Error: Received network error or non-101 status code after upgrading to Node.js 23
Problem: I am using the Gremlin package in my Node.js application to connect to Amazon Neptune. Everything works fine with Node.js version 20.18, but when I upgrade to Node.js 23 (the latest version), I get the following error:
Error fetching categories: Error: Received network error or non-101 status code.
    at failWebsocketConnection (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11629:18)
    at Object.processResponse (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11842:13)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:10623:23
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:151:7

My code is this
export function getGremlinTraversal() {
    if (!g) {
        const neptuneEndpoint = process.env.NEPTUNE_DB_ENDPOINT || '';
        const dc = new DriverRemoteConnection(neptuneEndpoint, { rejectUnauthorized: false });
        const graph = new Graph();
        g = graph.traversal().withRemote(dc);
    }

    return g;
}


Downgrading to Node.js 20.18 resolves the issue, but I want to use Node.js 23.
Verified that the connection string and endpoint are correct.

